# calling a function using defined header in C++

Tags: c++

I am relatively new to C++. I am trying to call a function using defined header. I have following 2 files(in addition to enter.h file):

// 1. main.cpp

```
 #include "enter.h"
 #include<iostream>
 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
 int intdemo=enter();
 cout << "The result is: " << intdemo<< endl;
}
```

// 2. enter.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
   using namespace std;
   int enter()
   {
   int thisisanumber;
     cout<<"Please enter a number: ";
     cin>>thisisanumber;
     return thisisanumber;
   }
```

I am getting the following error message "void value not ignored as it ought to be". and is pointed to the second line of the main function where value of the variable "intdemo" is assigned

Can anyone suggest how to fix this error? i have searched some of the similar posts here but cannot able to understand the problem. Since i am a beginner, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does enter.h look like?

Comment: Thanks sir. you nailed it. I mistakenly put void there in the enter.h file. Problem is solved now. Thanks.

Comment: Would you like me to post it as an answer or are you going to delete your question?

Comment: you can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your header file probably declares the function `enter()` to return `void` (this was confirmed in the comments).

Changing this to match your function definition will solve the problem, as well as an unresolved external error you will most likely be getting as a side effect of this.